# YouTube Player API -- define "native play button"

Tags: youtube-api

According to the API the playcount for a video is only incremented when a "native play button" is used. What counts as a "native play button?"

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#playVideo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answerin my own q here

The chromeless player has a large play button over the video by default, this is the ONLY native play button for the chromeless youtube player -- JS/AS implementations aren't counted.
The native player (with default chrome) has two play buttons -- one next to the scrubber, and the large one over the video.